# Adding an entry to GRUB?

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed by side of windows 7. Windows 7 is installed on sda7. But due to one reason or another it doesn't show up in the GRUB menu. So please help me out in adding it.

I've seen lots of tutorials online. I tried Boot Repair but none of them seemed to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Post link to BootInfo report from Boot-Repair. If you have MBR partitioning with BIOS boot, Windows will only boot from a primary partition (sda1 thru sda4). If you had another Windows install before all the boot files for the install in sda7 were in that previous install.

Answer (score 0):

First try and install BURG. Mostly it should work.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
>
> sudo burg-install "(hd0)"

Actually, that is what the final code is. It took me a while to understand what to put instead of HD0. So I just put in "/dev/sda" and it worked out fine.

Reboot to see if the problem continues.

Otherwise, do this. Copy "/etc/burg/burg.cfg" to your desktop. Then run this code:

> gksu gedit /etc/burg/burg.cfg

Look for something like "menuentry". If there is some Ubuntu related one, and none with Windows, then copy the Ubuntu one and paste it right below it. And then change the name with Windows and Partition name with the one that you have Windows on.

Nothing will go wrong, as you are not modifying the Ubuntu's menuentry. So you will still be able to log into Ubuntu, even if you are not able to boot into Windows. In case you are not, then boot into live CD and run Boot Repair.

Hope I help!